# Query two tables as one from different namespaces

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables in a PostgreSQL database that contains two tables that differ only by namespace: `Japan.Revenue` and `Korea.Revenue`. I want to query them as there is one table only.

E.g

```
  SELECT productgroup, sum(transactionvalue)
  FROM  ???? (Something that combines the two tables) 
  Group by productgroup where ....
```

How do I do that?

I need the Korea and Japan results combined. So far I did sent 2 queries and combined the result in the app. There must be a better way

Comment: Which table should be selected from in this case, and how would you expect Postgres would resolve this situation?

Comment: Tim, sorry for not being clear, my apologies. I’m looking for a way to combine the two tables as if they were just one aggregated one. So the AP reports run nicely

Comment: I guess you can use a sub select with the two tables as a `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fully-qualify the table names and union the results.
It's possible to do more than a simple select for the inner queries, but because you are doing an aggregation, you need to do it outside.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-union.html

```
SELECT productgroup, sum(transactionvalue)
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM Japan.Revenue
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM Kora.Revenue
) sub
GROUP BY productgroup
WHERE ....
;
```

Edit: Now using UNION ALL from comments below.

Comment: Awesome. Thought (tongue in cheek) Unions were a thing of the past in US #punintended

Comment: DO NOT USE `UNION`!  This will remove duplicates.  You should use `UNION ALL`.

Comment: You're right @GordonLinoff, good spot. I've editing the answer.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 SELECT productgroup, sum(transactionvalue)
  FROM  korea  
  Group by productgroup
union all
SELECT productgroup, sum(transactionvalue)
  FROM  japon  
  Group by productgroup
```

when you have same column with same type best way to combine is union
and you can group by it outside of select too.